# How to print insert in awk loop

Tags: awk

How to print the file name in the loop? I want to print the file name and the average value of column 4 at same line:

```
for i in `ls *cov`
do
awk '{sum +=$4;n++}END{print sum/n}' $i
done
```

I mean I want to

```
awk '{sum +=$4;n++}END{print $i\t sum/n}' $i
```

Answer (score 1):

You can use bash variables in an awk script using the `-v` flag:

```
awk -v file=$i '{sum +=$4;n++}END{print file\t sum/n}' $i
```

But, there is also the [built in awk variable](https://www.chemie.fu-berlin.de/chemnet/use/info/gawk/gawk_11.html) `FILENAME`:

```
 awk '{sum +=$4;n++}END{print FILENAME\t sum/n}' $i
```

Which is much cleaner since you aren't passing around variables.

Answer (score 1):

Lose the loop (see [why-is-using-a-shell-loop-to-process-text-considered-bad-practice](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/169716/why-is-using-a-shell-loop-to-process-text-considered-bad-practice)) and just use:

```
awk -v OFS='\t' '{sum+=$4} ENDFILE{print FILENAME, (FNR>0 ? sum/FNR : 0); sum=0}' *cov
```

The above uses GNU awk for ENDFILE, there's simple tweaks for other awks but the important things are:

1. A surrounding shell loop is neither required nor desirable.
2. The variable `n` isn't needed since awk has builtin variables.
3. You have to protect yourself from divide by zero on empty files.